# Cannot load Magento site using MAMP Pro

Tags: svn, magento, phpmyadmin, mamp

So I managed to get my Magento site repository checked out locally with Cornerstone (Mac SVN), the database imported into PHPMyAdmin via the Terminal command line, changed the core config table base url (www.mydomain.com to mydomain.localhost), added the local.xml with the right credentials to app/etc/local (SVN is set up to ignore it) and added mydomain.localhost in MAMP.

Not sure if I'm forgetting anything, but I get a big list of errors when I try to bring up mydomain.localhost or mydomain.localhost/admin.

I know it's a shot in the dark, but figured I'd see if anyone had any ideas, if I missed a step, or if anyone has run into this before.

Big list of errors:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/54760147/errors.txt

Comment: Really not sure how this issue was off topic for SO...but okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I did two things wrong, not sure which was the culprit (or both):

- Local.xml had the wrong encryption key in it
- Core config base urls
  were missing the slash at the end `http://mydomain.localhost` instead
  of `http://mydomain.localhost/`

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a big list of errors — you have a single exception being thrown.  The big list of errors is a callstack, showing you the code execution path that led to your error.

If you follow that trace you'll find this

```
        [10] => Array
            (
                [file] => /Applications/MAMP/mydomain/trunk/app/code/local/RichardMason/Profile/sql/profile_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php
                [line] => 9
                [function] => run
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 

ALTER TABLE pm_profile
ADD `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' AFTER `content`;


                    )

            )
```

It looks like your `RichardMason_Profile` module has a setup resource script that's attempting to add the column `link` to the table `pm_profile`.  This explains the single error message at the top of your single error

```
    [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'link'
```

As to **why** this is happening — that's harder to say and involves too many unknowns.  If the table already has this column, is means this resource script may have already run, but for some reason your database's `core_resource` table doesn't know about it (which is why it would try to run right now)

Lacking any more context, I'd recommend backing up the database, dropping the link column from this table, clearing your cache, and reloading the page.  This will let the script run unimpeded.